# Extract word from file with regex after finding another word and double points delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, file

I want to extract word from file after finding a reference word and having the word which is just after this referenced word and colon position, for example:

```
XXXXXXXX............REFERENCE : word_to_extract .....XXXXXXX
```

How can i extract the `word_to_extract`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pattern: `(?<=reference_word\s?:\s?)([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)`

Explanations:

```
(?<=             # positive lookbehind
reference_word   # literally reference_word, could be changed
\s?              # none or one space 
:                # literally colon
\s?)             # none or one space
([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)  # word to extract (letters, digits, underscores)
```

And the code:

```
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
String pattern = "(?<=reference_word\\s?:\\s?)([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)";
String testString = "XXX...reference_word : word_to_extract ...XXXX ...reference_word: word_to_extract2 ...reference_word :word_to_extract3 scz";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(testString);
while (m.find()) {
  allMatches.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(allMatches);
```

Output:

```
 [word_to_extract, word_to_extract2, word_to_extract3]
```